# Unable to read a json file with read_json

Tags: json, pandas, python-2.7, encoding

I'm trying to read a json file but I'm retrieving  a ValueError: Invalid octet in UTF-8 sequence when decoding 'string'

I'm using the folowing code to read it:

```
df1 =  pd.read_json('input/201704_Usage_Bicimad.json', lines=True)
```

Json file can be downloded from:
https://opendata.emtmadrid.es/Datos-estaticos/Datos-generales-(1) just clicking on "Datos de uso de Abril de 2017" to download it

I have tried changin enconding formats:

```
df1 =  pd.read_json('input/201704_Usage_Bicimad.json', lines=True, encoding="iso-8859-1")

df1 =  pd.read_json('input/201704_Usage_Bicimad.json', lines=True, encoding="latin-1")

df1 =  pd.read_json('input/201704_Usage_Bicimad.json', lines=True, encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

In all cases the same error is retrieved

Not idea how to proceed, how to identify the correct encoding format or how to identify the character that is given me problems

Update: After some comments received I have tested in Python 3 and it works. The point is that I need it running in Python 2.7

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. File is being read fine for me with `python 3.6.5` and `pandas 0.24.2`

Comment: I'm using python 2.7

Comment: Which encoding format are you using?

Comment: Just the default - utf8 - read in with `pd.read_json('input/201704_Usage_Bicimad.json', lines=True)`

Comment: tried with python 2.7?

Comment: Confirmed that in Python 3 it works but still having poblems with python 2.7